# How to merge this properly?

Tags: geometry

Ok, this question may have been asked a few times already but in this case I couldnt figure it out through the other questions.

I wanted to make an flying island like this
[image]

And I actually did it and created this thing by merging two landscapes (Blender Landscape Addon), but I literally have no idea how I did it. I just read something about merging and pressed some buttons and it kinda worked.
The problem with this model is, that it has very messy geometry, disconnected vertices all over the places. When I try to recreate it, it does not work, because I can´t figure out how I have done this in the first place.

How can you create an island like this, that also could be shown in the foreground? Is there a better way than just somehow merging two landscapes together?

Comment: you could use a mix of sculpt and modeling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **A.N.T. Landscape Generator add-on** but **tweak the settings until you get an inverted mountain**.

Here CG Geek briefly explains what he did in order to create the kind of island you would like to make: https://youtu.be/kQ0x0R_yHrs?t=171

Comment: I used that method, but I wanted to try to merge them together in a way that looks like the one in the picture, is there a way to merge them with something like the boolean modifier or do you have to align the vertices manually

Comment: I think you could use Vertex Snapping to your advantage. If you want to get a smoother blend after that, try joining both of the meshes, doing a Merge by Distance just to be sure there's no overlapping geometry and adding a Subdivision Surface modifier or a Smooth modifier. You can also try beveling the merged edge loop. Try any of these options and let me know if they work!

Comment: I think that works, cant tell, because the problem I have got now is that the landscapes are angular, which causes them to not look like islands. In CG Geeks video his islands at one point dont have this angular shape, did he just cut that off using the knife tool or sth else to change the angular shape?

Comment: I am not sure about that. 

Comment: ok, I will try to figure that part out, thanks for your help :D

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.